# Groovy и Андроид - работают ли вместе?

Tags: groovy, android, java

Здравствуйте. Недавно прочитал про Groovy и выделил для себя несколько приятных плюсов по сравнению с Java и потому возник такой вот вопрос.

На Java пишу только под Андроид (для десктопных больше C++ нравится), и Groovy во многом облегчил бы написание приложений.

Есть ли возможность писать на Groovy под Андроид?

Comment: Баловство! Java тоже упрощает написание приложений!

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал использование kotlin для этих целей. В целом создателей языка вдохновил Groovy (правда, язык сделали статически типизированным), и очень много моментов взяты из Groovy + официальная поддержка андроида + вес библиотеки ядра Groovy в разы уступает kotlin'у

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конечно, есть. Начиная с Groovy 2.4 есть полная поддержка приложений для Андройда.
Выполнена она в виде [плагина для Грейдла][1]. Документация там довольно подробная, с примерами. Если есть конкретные вопросы, их лучше публиковать отдельно.

Comment: не исключено, что в 12 году не было :)

Comment: с того момента как ответ стал неправильным, прошло достаточно времени, чтобы это исправить.

Comment: хотел написать: мне кажется что сюда не заходили после ответа, но второй ответ как-то оперативно удалили :):):)

Comment: Боюсь, ТС уже не вернется, чтобы принять ответ.

Comment: Всё? Убили? Насмерть?

Comment: @JBaruch, что поделать, он сомневался в groovy...

Comment: ну иногда you have to do what you have to to.